# How can I add exceptions to the files the Hacked! module looks at?

Tags: 7

I use the Hacked! module, which I generally like, but I also delete all the unnecessary text files from the Drupal root (*.txt except of course for robots.txt) because they just clutter up my root.  (As an aside, they ought to be moved to /docs or something like that in Drupal 8.)

How would I make Hacked! ignore them (even if I have to hack Hacked!)?